# How to correct a GitHub repository's dependency graph?

Tags: python, github, requirements.txt

In a GitHub repository, I have a Python `requirements.txt` with the following content:

```
pandas==1.0.5
praw==7.1.0
```

While [the dependency graph generated by GitHub](https://github.com/vmussa/sdbase/network/dependencies) pointed correctly to PRAW's official repository, it mistook pandas'. How to correct it so it points to pandas' actual GitHub repository?

Comment: By contacting GitHub to let them know about this. SO can't help you.

Comment: @AKX I see. I assumed that there should be some kind of API that I don't know about since pandas is a really famous Python package. It is curious that a package this big can't be recognized correctly, with the only option to resolve this being direct contact.